# Nested item should scroll, not its container

Tags: html, css, flexbox, overflow

I am having a setup like this:

```html
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; height: 500px">
  <div>
    <div>Tab menu</div>
    <div>Tab content</div>
  </div>
  <div>Content of item 2</div>
  <div>Content of item 3</div>
</div>
```

When the content of my outer div overflows, then I want the tab content to be scrollable.

If I set the first child div to `overflow: auto`, then both the tab menu and the tab content are part of the scrollable content, but I only want the tab content to be scrollable.

Comment: Do you mean by oterdiv grows because of the content of Tab grows.

Comment: Yes, the tab content grows and then the outer div overflows.

Answer (score 1):

> If I set the first child div to `overflow: auto`, then both the tab menu and the tab content are part of the scrollable content, but I only want the tab content to be scrollable.

Yes, because both the tab menu and tab content are in the same container.

If you want only the tab content to be scrollable, then isolate that content in its own container.

Finally, if you don't want to use additional fixed heights, use a nested flex container.

```css
#container {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#tab-info {
  min-height: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#tab-content {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="tab-info">
    <div>Tab menu</div>
    <div id="tab-content">
      <div>Tab content</div>
      <div>Tab content</div>
      <div>Tab content</div>
      <div>Tab content</div>
      <div>Tab content</div>
      <div>Tab content</div>
      <div>Tab content</div>
      <div>Tab content</div>
      <div>Tab content</div>
      <div>Tab content</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>Content of item 2</div>
  <div>Content of item 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

In that case keep the Tab Conetnt div fixed height, and keep it's overflow:auto.

Comment: But then I would still need to know the height of all the other divs to identify how I should set the height of the tab content, wouldn't I?

Comment: You have to make it on percentage basis and minimum and maximum height.

Comment: And one tab only visisble at one point of time, other will be hidden. So you dont have to caluclate much either.